# qBittorrent does not run external shell script

Tags: qbittorrent

I set qBittorrent-nox to run a shell script after completing a download, but nothing happens. If I change **Run external program on torrent completion** to a built-in command (say `mv "%F" "%F-copy"`), then it runs fine.

The shell script basically does the same thing:

```
path=$1
mv "$path" "$path-copy"
```

I put the shell script under **/usr/local/bin/movefile**, and set owner to root and permission to 755. Using `sudo -u` as the user running qBittorrent-nox, running command `movfile "/home/qbuser/downloads/completed/123.file"` does move **123.file** to **123.file-copy**

However, if I change **Run external program on torrent completion** to `movfile "%F"`, nothing happens.

What might have I missed?

Comment: @waltinator Your comment is **not relevant** to the question.  Many of your comments seem to be canned comments as well, so please update whatever mechanism you use for your comments to be less abrasive in general, as well as know *when* to actually post a comment or not as comments like this one you just posted here are not relevant nor helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I'm using it wrong. When running an external program, qBittorrent does not spawn a shell. Had to change the external program to **bash** then call my shell script (`/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/movfile "%F"`).

Comment: Did you try adding a **shebang** to your script (`#! /bin/sh` should be sufficient, since it doesn't appear to use any bash-specific syntax)? I suspect that would allow you to use your `movfile` command directly, as you originally wanted